# Copying to clipboard using vuejs2

Tags: vuejs2, clipboard

What is wrong with the below code for copying to clipboard using vue and vue-clipboard?

`<button  v-clipboard:copy="message">Copy</button>`

```
data: {
 message:"text to copy"
}
```

});

https://jsfiddle.net/29zhwcdf/2/

Data is not being copied to clipboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to use: [Vue.use(*`vueClipboards`*)](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/plugins.html#Using-a-Plugin), before instantiating your Vue application.

Working example:

```js
Vue.use(vueClipboards); // Add this before 'new Vue({..})'
var apptest = new Vue({
  el: "#apptest",
  data: {
    message: "text to copy"
  },
  methods: {
    handleSuccess(e) {
      console.log(e);
    },
    handleError(e) {
      console.log(e);
    },
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue-clipboards@1.2.4/dist/vue-clipboards.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="apptest">
    <button v-clipboard="message" @success="handleSuccess" @error="handleError">Copy</button>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```